# Extract data from curl output using sed, awk, cut or python3

Tags: bash, shell, curl, awk, sed

I am trying to extract one url from a curl command's output in shell.

The curl command which I am running is :

```
curl -s "http://HOSTNAME.com/api/v4/projects/18/merge_requests?source_branch=samm_6819"
```

which gives output something like this :

```
[{"id":244,"iid":69,"project_id":18,"title":"bug 6819","description":"","state":"merged","created_at":"2021-09-04T06:51:05.988Z","updated_at":"2021-09-04T06:52:03.869Z","merged_by":{"id":4,"name":"SOME NAME ","username":"SOMEUSERNAME","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/baa4538f891a621a8e5480aa9ac404a6?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"http://HOSTNAME/SOMEUSERNAME"},"merged_at":"2021-09-04T06:52:03.997Z","closed_by":null,"closed_at":null,"target_branch":"master","source_branch":"samm_6819","user_notes_count":0,"upvotes":0,"downvotes":0,"author":{"id":1,"name":"Administrator","username":"root","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/81fasf149c17eba1d66803dc0877828900?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"http://HOSTNAME/root"},"assignees":[],"assignee":null,"reviewers":[],"source_project_id":18,"target_project_id":18,"labels":[],"draft":false,"work_in_progress":false,"milestone":null,"merge_when_pipeline_succeeds":true,"merge_status":"can_be_merged","sha":"1e14427dd70862265b55fsa0e38f4e980d5f65524","merge_commit_sha":"34240a857d7d1a852f9c3d4safa3f031ef3bd35225","squash_commit_sha":null,"discussion_locked":null,"should_remove_source_branch":false,"force_remove_source_branch":false,"reference":"!69","references":{"short":"!69","relative":"!69","full":"SOMEPROJECTNAME-af/test!69"},"web_url":"http://HOSTNAME.com/GROUPNAME/PROJECTNAME/-/merge_requests/69","time_stats":{"time_estimate":0,"total_time_spent":0,"human_time_estimate":null,"human_total_time_spent":null},"squash":false,"task_completion_status":{"count":0,"completed_count":0},"has_conflicts":false,"blocking_discussions_resolved":true,"approvals_before_merge":null}]
```

Out of all this data, I need output to be :

```
http://HOSTNAME.com/GROUPNAME/PROJECTNAME/-/merge_requests/69
```

I need this url which I need to print somewhere. I am not sure what can be used here either awk, sed , cut or anything with pipe with the curl command to get output of this url.

Can someone help me please?
I never wanted to ask this here but I am running out of options on what could be the best way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Use `jq` to parse json

Answer (score 2):

Best option here is to use `jq`:

```
json='[{"id":244,"iid":69,"project_id":18,"title":"bug 6819","description":"","state":"merged","created_at":"2021-09-04T06:51:05.988Z","updated_at":"2021-09-04T06:52:03.869Z","merged_by":{"id":4,"name":"SOME NAME ","username":"SOMEUSERNAME","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/baa4538f891a621a8e5480aa9ac404a6?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"http://HOSTNAME/SOMEUSERNAME"},"merged_at":"2021-09-04T06:52:03.997Z","closed_by":null,"closed_at":null,"target_branch":"master","source_branch":"samm_6819","user_notes_count":0,"upvotes":0,"downvotes":0,"author":{"id":1,"name":"Administrator","username":"root","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/81fasf149c17eba1d66803dc0877828900?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"http://HOSTNAME/root"},"assignees":[],"assignee":null,"reviewers":[],"source_project_id":18,"target_project_id":18,"labels":[],"draft":false,"work_in_progress":false,"milestone":null,"merge_when_pipeline_succeeds":true,"merge_status":"can_be_merged","sha":"1e14427dd70862265b55fsa0e38f4e980d5f65524","merge_commit_sha":"34240a857d7d1a852f9c3d4safa3f031ef3bd35225","squash_commit_sha":null,"discussion_locked":null,"should_remove_source_branch":false,"force_remove_source_branch":false,"reference":"!69","references":{"short":"!69","relative":"!69","full":"SOMEPROJECTNAME-af/test!69"},"web_url":"http://HOSTNAME.com/GROUPNAME/PROJECTNAME/-/merge_requests/69","time_stats":{"time_estimate":0,"total_time_spent":0,"human_time_estimate":null,"human_total_time_spent":null},"squash":false,"task_completion_status":{"count":0,"completed_count":0},"has_conflicts":false,"blocking_discussions_resolved":true,"approvals_before_merge":null}]'
echo $json | jq -r '.[].web_url'
```

Comment: Hi actually , I am running this curl command which I am using in a script : `curl -s "http://HOSTNAME.com/api/v4/projects/18/merge_requests?source_branch=samm_6819"
` How can I use jq as a single line command?

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Is the output of the command just the json? if so: `curl -s "http://HOSTNAME.com/api/v4/projects/18/merge_requests?source_branch=samm_6819" |  jq -r '.[].web_url' `

Comment: Hi , The thing is, we are running a CI pipeline inside which we will run the command, and in our most of servers we do not have jq installed. Hence we are searching for something which does not make use of jq. :(

Comment: @SameerAtharkar Adjust your CI environment to make sure `jq` is installed. Using something that's not JSON-aware to try to parse JSON is like using a screwdriver to pound a nail. Wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`

```
sed 's/.*:.\(http.[^"]*\).*/\1/'
```

It will match the last occurance of `http` through to the first occurance of `"` after http.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cat file` in place of `curl...` for demonstration, this will work **on the input you show** using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat file | sed 's/.*"web_url":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'
http://HOSTNAME.com/GROUPNAME/PROJECTNAME/-/merge_requests/69
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl

```
$ perl -ne ' /.*"web_url":"([^"]+)"/ and print "$1\n" ' sameer.txt
http://HOSTNAME.com/GROUPNAME/PROJECTNAME/-/merge_requests/69
```

Another method:

```
perl -ne ' while( /"web_url":"([^"]+)"/g ) { $x=1; $t=$1 } print "$t\n" if $x; $x=0 ' sameer.txt
```